# Create a two part regex to isolate part of sentence

Tags: python, regex, string

I have a list of "sentences" (they're not really sentences but in a general sense, they can be seen as such)

```
Microsoft Hortense Desktop - French
Microsoft David Desktop - English (United States)
Microsoft Zira Desktop - English (United States)
Microsoft Helena Desktop - Spanish (Spain)
Microsoft Hazel Desktop - English (Great Britain)
```

I'm trying to use a regex to isolate the language in each of these lines.

I have found one that allows me to detect the first part of the strings but I would need a way to skip the language and then detect the space and everything between parentheses following the language.

What I have so far: `^(.*?)-\`

I'm very inexperienced with regex so I'll gladly take any advice and help on how to use them !

Comment: `re.findall(r"\((.*)\)", tgt_text)` something like this? `re.match()` and `re.search()` are slightly different. `re.match()` matches from the start of the string on, and `re.search()` doesn't care where the match starts in the target string.

Answer (score 0):

Well if data in the parentheses is all you need... why not just skip all of it and go straight for it?

```
.*\((.*)\)
```

https://regex101.com/r/OexsTg/1

. means any character. * means any number of times.
So .* means any character any number of times.

Then I specify I specifically want a ( by escaping it because it is also a expression in regex, \ escapes. So (.

Then I make the match group starting with (

Then I say... again, any character any amount of time.

Ending the group and closing with the expected parantheses.

I hope this helps!

EDIT::

If you want the full language, so also that part left of parentheses and right of the dash. Use:

```
.*- (.*) ?(\(.*\))?
```

https://regex101.com/r/lbLC9I/1

EDIT-EDIT::

```
.*- ([A-z]*)
```

https://regex101.com/r/BzLKcw/1

Comment: @usr2564301 Yeah good point, did not consider that, updated the answer with a regex that does that.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, unfortunately what I want is slightly more complex. If I take `Microsoft David Desktop - English (United States)` as an example, I would like the regex to ONLY return `English`. Do you see what I mean ?

Comment: @MaxMichel Ooooh i thought you wanted to united states part as well... would this then be your answer? (See last edit)